# Setting the log level causes fabric to complain with 'No handlers could be found for logger "ssh.transport"'

Tags: python, logging, fabric

The following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from   fabric.api import env, run
import logging

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

env.host_string = "%s@%s:%s" % ('myuser', 'myhost', '22')
res = run('date', pty = False)
```

Produces the following output:

```
[myuser@myhost:22] run: date
No handlers could be found for logger "ssh.transport"
[myuser@myhost:22] out: Thu Mar 29 16:15:15 CEST 2012
```

I would like to get rid of this annoying error message: `No handlers could be found for logger "ssh.transport"`
The problem happens when setting the log level (setLevel).

How can I solve this? I need to set the log level, so skipping that won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hack is ugly but works:

```
# This is here to avoid the mysterious messages: 'No handlers could be found for logger "ssh.transport"'

class MyNullHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        pass

bugfix_loggers = { }
def bugfix(name):
    global bugfix_loggers
    if not name in bugfix_loggers:
        # print "Setting dummy logger for '%s'" % (name)
        logging.getLogger(name).addHandler(MyNullHandler())
        bugfix_loggers[name] = True
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the logging system. You can make the error go away by doing so in your app thusly:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig( level=logging.INFO )
```

Note: this uses the default Formatter, which is not terribly useful.  You might consider something more like:

```
import logging
FORMAT="%(name)s %(funcName)s:%(lineno)d %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.INFO)
```